# How to increase volume beyond 100% on Xubuntu from command?

Tags: 16.04, sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio

I want to map a keyboard shortcut to such a command so that I can increase/decrease the volume beyond 100% using a keyboard shortcut anytime. I have tried pactl and amixer that don't go beyond 100%, and pavucontrol that brings up the graphical window (I don't want that). I'm using Xubuntu 16.04. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you use `pactl`? let me know if my answer works for you... if not I'll improve it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `pactl` to change "set-sink-volume":

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 120%
```

you can do it relatively too:

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 +10%
```

Comment: I have tried both of these ways. The volume reaches 100% and then doesn't increase further. For amixer I tried `amixer -D pulse sset Master 130%` and also like this: `amixer -D pulse sset Master +10%`. Neither of them go beyond 100%.

Comment: Are you sure that you are watching out the correct volume (output device ) instead of system sound?

Comment: How do you check that? All I am checking is the volume shown on top right corner, and the volume at which I can listen to my songs.

Comment: In terminal run `pavucontrol` a window will show up, go to the "output devices" tab. here you can see the volume status, run those commands see if they are working. if you don't have `pavucontrol` install it: `sudo apt install pavucontrol`.

Comment: Thank you! So `0` was for the HDMI apparently and it used to increase. I tried `pactl set-sink-volume 1 120%` and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)